# style highmaps mapbubbles onclick

Tags: javascript, highmaps

I have a map like this: http://jsfiddle.net/67ex7kd7/5/

I'm trying to make the mapbubbles a darker shade of pink when they are selected. I've tried using the mapbubble states options like this:

```
        states:{
            hover: {
                borderColor: '#903d50',
                borderWidth: '3px',
                brightness: 1,
                color: '#903d50',
                enabled: true
            },
            normal: {
                animation:true
            },
            select: {
                borderColor: '#76a01e',
                borderWidth: '3px',
                color: '#76a01e',
                enabled: true 
            }
        },
```

within the mapbubble series, but I'm not having any luck. Not sure how to access the selected styles. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i experienced there is only one way to achieve what you are looking for via marker's plotoption:

```
plotOptions: {
                mapbubble: {
                    marker: {
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        fillColor: "#f06586",
                        states: {
                            select: {
                                fillColor: '#76a01e',
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                lineColor: '#76a01e'
                            },
                           hover: {
                               fillColor: '#903d50',
                               lineWidth: 3,
                                lineColor: '#903d50'
                            },

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67ex7kd7/9/